# Master Detail View Controller Crashes second time to Detail View

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7

I have an iOS 7 App with a master/detail split view controller.  The first time it goes to the detail view it is fine the second it crashes .  I have tried using Zomibies to find the problem of the deallocated memory and it is giving me UISplitViewController_CalculateDelegateHiddenMasterOrientation which in in UI Kit not my code.  The same problem occurs if you rotate after being at the detail view.  I have no code but the standard Apple code at the detail view that deals with the SplitView
Possibly related when in Portrait mode after being at the detail view the popover button disappears
the App is finished and works excellent on the iPhone,Thanks

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"This Log Is On THe Detail View");
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
[self preferredStatusBarStyle];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTableBetween"    object:nil];

if (selectedSection == 10) {
    [starButton setHidden:YES];
}
NSLog(@"WebView Size = %i",[[webView   stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')  [0].style.webkitTextSize"]intValue]);
textFontSize = 100;



detailedItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[detailedItem setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedItem] forKey:@"item"];
[detailedItem setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedSection] forKey:@"section"];

[navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[self configureView];
if (comingFromiPad) {
    NSLog(@"comingFromiPad");
    [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

if ([favorites containsObject:detailedItem]) {
    [starButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starWhiteFilled.png"]      `   forState:UIControlStateNormal];`
    starTapped = YES; //FAVORITED
} else {
    [starButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starWhiteOutline.png"]   forState:UIControlStateNormal];//UNFAVORITED
    starTapped = NO;
}

NSLog(@"Detail viewDidLoad selectedItem = %i",selectedItem);
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
favorites = [[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"favorites"] mutableCopy];

}
```

This if from the detail and it does not get here the second time

Here is the crash log
          Incident Identifier: 166E3644-A3E8-459B-A3C7-729C8639D327
    CrashReporter Key:   03391171a6c2809e94f6bee3f4adf948a4986bce
    Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
    Process:             Constitution [733]
    Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/3147DC34-7536-4843-B920-   7DA4E750E820/Constitution.app/Constitution
    Identifier:          net.multieducator.Constitution
    Version:             1.0 (1.0)
    Code Type:           ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

```
Date/Time:           2013-11-19 12:12:48.502 -0500
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.3 (11B511)
Report Version:      104

 Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
 Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
 0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a00bb26 objc_msgSend + 6
  1   UIKit                             0x32426cd0 -[UISplitViewController    _calculateDelegateHiddenMasterOrientations] + 56
2   UIKit                           0x32428906 -[UISplitViewController     setViewControllers:] + 1390
   UIKit                            0x324c95ca -[UIStoryboardReplaceSegue perform] + 686
4   Constitution                    0x00023490 -[BetweenViewController    tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (BetweenViewController.m:415)
5   UIKit                           0x321318b6 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1074
6   UIKit                           0x321e4f76 -[UITableView      _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 210
 7   UIKit                          0x32094fb6 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
 8   UIKit                          0x3200d1ee _afterCACommitHandler + 426
 9   CoreFoundation                 0x2f86d1ca         __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2f86ab6c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 280
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2f86aeae __CFRunLoopRun + 726
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2f7d5c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2f7d5a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
14  GraphicsServices                0x344c927e GSEventRunModal + 134
15  UIKit                           0x32079044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
16  Constitution                    0x0001bf1a main (main.m:16)
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a518ab4 start + 0
```

Comment: Posting some code will help

Comment: Not sure what code to show, since its not clear where the problem is.  It crashed on beginning the segue but from what I can tell the crash occurs as its trying to enter the detail view and does not know what the state of the view is.  I am using ARC so I ma not sure how anything that is needed is be deallocated

Comment: Code that is related to presenting / pushing the detail view and code that happens inside the detail view loading (eg `init`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` etc)

Comment: Posting the crashlog and callstack would also help tremendously.

Comment: Problem solved; needed to reset the App delegate when going to detail view the second time